# How to add an eventListener Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to set up an event listener using Symfony  2.7 and I am newbie in the Symfony world.

So when the user comes to this (/configuration/family/{code}/edit) url, I want to set up an event listener with getting/reading to database and also when the user updates textarea for this to be inside the database.

I have the template in place:

```
<div class="AknFieldContainer">
<div class="AknFieldContainer-header">
    <label class="AknFieldContainer-label control-label required" for="<%- fieldName%>">

        <textarea></textarea> // it should be added in this textarea. 
    </label>
</div>
<div class="AknFieldContainer-inputContainer">
</div>
```

Could someone help me on how to begin using Event Listener's ?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are about to do, but when a User comes to a link, why you need event listener on that, the controller action is taking care of this, isn't it?
Also if you want to have his response saved from the textarea after just leaving it (without submitting) you should do this with jquery/ajax and a REST API to symfony.
Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the response Jozef. 
We are overwriting the vendor directory and I want to overwrite just this tiny piece of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link for the usage and configuration of event listeners in symfony2.7:
https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: Link only answered are frowned upon.  And in this particular case, it is not at all clear what is actually being asked.  The title is clear but the content is strange.

Comment: Once the user comes to this url, I want to fire up an event listener. 
Also I want when I user clicks on certain buttons, I want other event listeners to fire up. For example once the user clicks on a save button I want to fire up an event which is going to put inside the database some data.

Comment: @FortuneSoldier I understand your words individually but when taken together they make no sense to me.  I suspect you may be mixing up Javascript events with Symfony event listeners.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I believe that's the case in here. I believe that I am fixing javascript event through Symfony event handler (listener).